# Copying Pivot Table Formats

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble getting pivot table formats to copy to a new sheet. Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

```
someRange.Copy
someOtherRange.pasteSpecial xlPasteValues
someOtherRange.pasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Basically, I want an exact copy of the current view on a pivot table in a new sheet but I just want the values and formatting (and not be connected to the pivot table any longer). Doing this procedure by hand produces the correct result, but for some reason the formatting doesn't copy when I use the same approach via vba... Thoughts?

**Update:**
Exact code as requested:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
pivotSheet.Range(pivotSheet.usedRange.Cells(1, 2), pivotSheet.Cells(pivotSheet.usedRange.Rows.Count, pivotSheet.Columns.Count)).Copy
updatesSheet.Range(updatesSheet.Cells(1, 1), updatesSheet.Cells(pivotSheet.usedRange.Rows.Count, pivotSheet.usedRange.Columns.Count)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
updatesSheet.Range(updatesSheet.Cells(1, 1), updatesSheet.Cells(pivotSheet.usedRange.Rows.Count, pivotSheet.usedRange.Columns.Count)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: `pastSpecial` is not how you should spell that

Comment: true, though that was just a typo ... not the actual problem. Thanks though.

Comment: Hi, Still having the same issue myself. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("H1:I6").Copy

        With .Range("M7")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth. Though this is the same solution I've tried and for some reason I'm not getting the formatting. Wish I knew why... Think I'll just format it in code the hard way....

Comment: see update above... ill accept the answer, I agree this is what it *should* be. I'm just saying that it isn't actually doing this on my machine...

Comment: I think your problem can be sorted if you can upload a sample workbook. I won't be able to debug the above code as lot of things are not declared(I mean shown) in the above code.

Comment: What version of Excel both of you were using?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tried using this on entire worksheets with no success(copying old worksheet to new). I wonder if the issue issue is environmental?

Answer (score 0):

Before copying and pasting manually, start recording a macro. After you're finished, stop the recording and examine the recorded code. You'll get a bunch of extra stuff you can delete, but you'll also get the correct syntax for doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Already tried that - that's how I came up with the above code. When I do it by hand (and recording) the result is correct. But when I actually run the macro only the values are copied not the formats. thanks though.

Comment: haha and I'm sure it does on your machine. I'm just saying it doesn't on mine. You'll just have to trust me on that ;)

Comment: Can you try it out on another machine? I've run into plenty of machine-specific issues over the years.

Comment: I could but I've pretty much written my way around it at this point. May have something to do with the version of the pivot table but I don't really have the time/patience to debug that at this point. Thanks for your help though everyone.