# Copy pivot table values and formats

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I can't seem to be able to get the pivot table formats to get copied, I can only get the values to transfer. I am using this post as reference:[Copying Pivot Table Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418875/copying-pivot-table-formats)

here's my code:

```
Sub copyPaste(ByVal sht As Variant, ByVal cell As String)
Dim r As range
    pt.TableRange2.Offset(1, 0).Copy
    With wbReport.Sheets(sht).range(cell)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is the `.Offset(1, 0)`. When you offset that Range as I did, for some reason, the coloring formats don't get copied. My workaround for now is just to remove that tidbit and just copy the `TableRange2` then delete the corresponding top row of the table. Note that I am using mac excel 2011.