# Excel VBA: Preserve Bold Pivot Subtotal labels when copying Pivot to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to copy a pivot table into a new worksheet that contains the values of the pivot plus the subtotals in bold.  Here is what I have used from another post here ([Copying Pivot Table Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418875/copying-pivot-table-formats))

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("H1:I6").Copy

        With .Range("M7")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

However, when I use this code, all I get is the values in the pivot without the formatting.  I need to preserve the bold format of the subtotals so I can work with those a different way in the new worksheet.

I also had tried to determine subtotals using the text output (visibly, the non subtotals show a space, but when you look at the actual text value in the formula bar there is no space).

Any ideas?  Alternatively, is there a better solution to trying to determine which rows are subtotals after I copy out of the pivot?

Comment: Is there a way you could perhaps use Conditional Formatting on the Pivot Table?

Comment: I could, but the issue is none of the formatting is being preserved when I copy out of the pivot into another sheet.  The formatting I need (bolded subtotal labels) is already in the pivot.

Comment: Try using "xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme". I am not sure if this will past the pivot table, but as long as the entire pivot table isnt in the selection it shouldnt be able to.

Comment: If I do it manually, it appears to preserve the formatting but when incorporated into a macro, all I get is the unformatted text.